# Capturing photos easily in android

Tags: java, android, storage, photo

I would like to have the user press a button and have the front camera take a single picture and add it to the gallery. I found this http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html which lets you use an intent to go to the preprogrammed preview however I don't want to use a preview I just want a picture taken. There is also a way to control every aspect of the picture taking process here http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html but thats more intended for people who want to make their own entire camera application which I don't need. Is there a simple way to do? Thanks.

Comment: Reread the tutorial you linked.  It shows how to take the picture.  It just launches the camera app to take it.  If you really don't want to launch the camera app, then the Camera class is the only answer, and you will have to do everything yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> but thats more intended for people who want to make their own entire camera application which I don't need

Yes, you do.

> Is there a simple way to do?

Not particularly. Writing code to support cameras is rather complex. `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is intended for more conventional uses of the camera, where the user cares about the picture and therefore wants to make sure the camera is pointed in the right direction, the subject is in focus, etc. You don't *have* to allow the user to confirm that the camera is pointed in the right direction, the subject is in focus, and so on, but then you have to write your own camera application.